# How to merge several ui elements into a listview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making a custom view which contains an `ExpandableListView`, a `CheckedTextView` and a `ListView` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/filtersDialogView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/filtersListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/onlyShowAvailableItemsCheckedTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:text="@string/OnlyShowAvailableItems" />

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/categoriesListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the `CheckTextView` is fixed and the two lists are scrolling independently (which is normal for that layout). Furthermore when I expand a list item from the `ExpandableListView`, the `CheckedTextView` and the other `ListView` become hidden. I'd like to make a single list with all these elements that could scroll and resize properly when I expand an element of the first list (the cells of the second list are not expandable). How can I do that? Is it possible to make it without having to modify the Adapters of the lists and the controller of the `CheckedTextView` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that? Is it possible to make it without having to modify
>   the Adapters of the lists and the controller of the CheckedTextView ?

I doubt that, especially as you have two scrolling views, the `ExpandableListView` and the `ListView`. I think your only option is a special adapter that will *simulate* the layout above. I had a custom `ExpandableListView` adapter that I modified into something that will simulate the layout like the one above. It's something raw so there could be some errors(I've tested it a little) and of course there are other things to work on. The code sample it's a little big so I put it here https://gist.github.com/3046887 .

Comment: I want to get rid of the dropdown icon that appear on the group views which don't expand. How can I do that?

Comment: @jafar Unfortunately that is one of the things you'll have to do yourself. Because you either have all the groups with the icon or all the groups don't have the icon  you'll have to manage yourself the state. I've modified the code at the link from my answer take another look at it(check the `getGroupView` method). You basically have to remove the icon from all groups, then in the layout file for the expanding groups add an `ImageView`. After all that, register a `OnGroupClickListener` and modify the image drawable based on the current state, folded/expanded.